# Internet keeps stopping working

Tags: internet

Edit: connection via cable

My internet randomly decides like every 10 hours to suddenly stop working. I have to turn off the connection and turn it on again. This always fixes the problem.

- I have windows 10 on the same machine and there is no problem
- still appears as connected, but `ping google.com` hangs

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Please clarify which connection method you use, Wired or wireless?

Comment: @Raffa sorry, the connection is via a cable

Comment: This could happen for many reasons including  DHCP lease time in your DHCP server, power saving settings on the network card as well as on the switch-port, power saving software .... and others. Please, try to investigate more and update your question so that we can help. Thank you